# Incompatible Types in If Statement

Tags: java

I am getting an incompatible types error message in my if statement. The variables "answer" and "input2" are both integers so I am not sure how the two are incompatible. Any help or insight would be much appreciated!

```
public static void addingGame()
{

    System.out.print("\n");

    System.out.println("********* Part 2: Adding Numbers **********");

    System.out.print("\n");

    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Would you like to add some numbers?(y/n)");
    String input = inputReader.next();

    while (!input.equals("y") && !input.equals("n"))
    {
        System.out.print("I need a y/n: ");
        input = inputReader.next();
    }    

    while (input.equals("y"))
    {
        Random numberGenerator = new Random();
        int randomNumber1 = numberGenerator.nextInt(10);
        int randomNumber2 = numberGenerator.nextInt(10);
        int answer = ((randomNumber1) + (randomNumber2));
        System.out.print( randomNumber1 + " + " + randomNumber2 + " =: ");
        int input2 = inputReader.nextInt();
        if (answer = input2)
        {
            System.out.print("Right! " + answer + " is the answer.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Sorry, " + answer + " is the answer.");
        }

        System.out.print("Would you like to play again?(y/n)");
        input = inputReader.next();
        while (!input.equals("y") && !input.equals("n"))
        {
            System.out.print("Sorry - I need a y/n: ");
            input = inputReader.next();
        }
    }    

    System.out.print("\n");

    System.out.print("Thanks - Let's move on to Part 3...");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the assignment operator `=` when you wanted to compare the values (`==`).  Change

```
if (answer = input2)
```

to

```
if (answer == input2)
```

The error came from the fact that the result of the assignment is still an `int`, where as the `if` condition expects a `boolean`, which `==` provides.